Facing EIO Error in StackBlitz Web Container
I am currently using StackBlitz SDK to embed a project in my website , but I am facing an EIO Error when I try to run the command npm run test:serve multiple times.
Error Details:
When I execute the command npm run test:serve more than 3 times, I encounter the following error:
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, write
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/.npm/_logs/2024-10-22T22_14_03_484Z-debug-0.log
jsh: spawn npm EIO

What Does This Mean?
From the error message, I understand that it indicates a low-level Input/Output (I/O) issue during file system operations. This could be related to:

Disk Issues (e.g., full disk or disk errors)
Permissions Problems
Hardware Failures
Resource Limits
However, the issue only occurs when I run the npm run test:serve command multiple times in quick succession. It does not seem to happen when I run the command once or when I run the npm run dev command multiple times.

What I Have Tried:

Re-running the Command: The error happens consistently when running the command more than three times.

CodeSandbox URL:
I have created a CodeSandbox where I've embedded StackBlitz using its SDK. The issue can be reproduced there.
CodeSandbox URL: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/knw455
Steps to Reproduce:

Open the provided CodeSandbox link.
Run the command npm run test:serve in the terminal (under the "Terminal" tab).
After the first successful run, re-run the command 3 times consecutively.
The EIO error should appear after running the command 3 times.

Question:
Has anyone encountered this EIO error before with StackBlitz SDK or CodeSandbox? If so, how can I resolve it? Is this related to disk permissions, resource limits, or something specific to running the StackBlitz embed with npm run test:serve?
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to fix this issue!
I tried running the command npm run test:serve multiple times in succession (more than 3 times), which should start the server and run tests successfully. I expected the tests to run without any issues and for the server to stay active. However, after running the command more than 3 times, I encountered an EIO error with the message npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, write, indicating a failure in writing to disk.
This error occurs consistently when running the command multiple times and prevents further execution of tests.

This issue has been fixed, It was due to resource constraints of Stackblitz web container & using webpack to compile test cases inside that, I migrated to Vite for the build process & the error is no longer there.
